# Google Nearline Storage - I want to remove bucket delete ability from editor

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Due to Seagate shutting down Evault LTS2, I am considering moving our cold archives to Google Nearline Storage.  I currently have the 60 day free trial account going and I am experimenting with buckets and members and permissions.

By default there are 3 relevant roles, Owner, Editor, and Viewer.  I would like to remove from Editor the ability to delete an entire bucket.

- Can I create my own role which has all the abilities of Editor except this? OR
- Can I adjust the permission on a bucket so that Editors cannot delete it

If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: We are also looking for a similar solution.  Ideally, a group of collaborators could use the developer console or command line to create buckets/objects, but would not have the ability to delete buckets and/or objects.  IAM's storage.objectCreator accomplishes this to some extent, but seems to disable browsing objects in the Developer Console in our projects.  Having both an objectCreator and a bucketCreator roles and with Dev Console access would be ideal for our use case.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to create a role that has all of the Editor abilities other than bucket deletion.

You can remove the project-editors group from the bucket acl with gsutil:

`gsutil acl ch -d editors-yourprojectnumber gs://your-bucket`

However, project editors will always have the ability to create and delete buckets in your project, so if you don't want someone to delete your bucket, project editor may not be the appropriate role for that user.

There is a caveat that may help in your situation: if you remove editors from the bucket ACL using the command above, that would remove project editors' write access (and delete access) for objects in that bucket. So project editors wouldn't be able to delete objects in the bucket.  Since buckets are required to be empty before they can be deleted, running the command above would protect any bucket that has objects in it from being deleted by project editors.

So if your goal is to protect data in the bucket(s), but you can live with deletion of already-empty buckets, I think you can achieve this with the command above.

Comment: Thanks Travis.  For my use I don't think that will work.  The people who are digitizing books and archiving the content need to be able to add the content to the bucket.  I was just hoping to safeguard against a total bucket deletion.

Comment: I like the idea of buckets being required to be empty before deletion, but I just tried it and was able to delete a bucket which had a file in it.

Comment: That should only be possible in a race condition case where the listing index of the bucket hasn't caught up with a recently-created object; it should not be possible generally.  Currently, write access to a bucket governs both creating and deleting objects in the bucket, so there's not sufficient granularity to specify "users can write but they can't overwrite or delete".

Comment: I just did another test, a bucket with files in it from a few days ago, and it does ask if I am sure, then it does allow deletion of a bucket with contents.  We are using Google Nearline buckets so I don't know if that is the difference from your experience.

Comment: What are you using to perform the deletion?  The web UI will recursively delete objects in the bucket.  If that is what you're doing, are you using a browser logged in with a user who actually has credentials to delete objects in the bucket?

Comment: Yes, the web UI allows this deletion of a bucket with content.

Comment: The web UI is authenticated as the user who is logged into the browser.  It must delete objects in the bucket prior to deleting object in the bucket, so if that user doesn't have permission to delete the objects in the bucket, it should fail.  Are you saying the user logged into the browser doesn't have write permission on the bucket, but is able to delete it (and the objects it contains) anyway?

Comment: No.  My goal is to prevent accidental deletion of buckets of content.  If the service would not allow the deletion of buckets with content that would be great.  Sounds like from gsutil that is the case.  But from the web UI, users with editor ability can indeed delete buckets with content.